# @Bean List doesn't work in implementation class

Tags: spring

I have List in @Bean in Config class:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public List<IBeer> beers(){
        List<IBeer> beers = new ArrayList<IBeer>();
        beers.add(new Warka("Warka", 4.5, 3.20));
        return beers;
    }
}
```

...and I'm trying to inject this Bean to this implementation:

```
public class Order implements IOrder {

    @Value("#{beers[0]}")
    private IBeer beer;

    @Autowired
    private List<IBeer> beers;

    public Order (IBeer beer) {
        super();
        this.beer = beer;
    }

    public void showOrder() {
        System.out.printf("nazwa: " + beer.getName() + "%n" +
               "procenty: " + beer.getAlcoholPercentage() + "%%" + "%n" +
               "cena: " + beer.getPrice() + "PLN" + "%n");
    }

    }
```

Class Warka has only constructor (string, double, double) and 3 getters for them, it implements interface IBeer.
Class Order implements interface IOrder.

Shouldn't it work?
My project is here:
https://github.com/dadziu/nawalmySie/tree/sec

```
wrz 20, 2018 5:34:47 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4fe3c938: startup date [Thu Sep 20 17:34:47 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/Dadziu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.8.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'pl.nawalmySie.implementation.Order' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:346)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1107)
at pl.nawalmySie.app.App.main(App.java:14)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please tells us what is the error that you encountered. Saying "It doesn't work" is not enough for us to understand precisely what the problem is and therefore to help you out.

Comment: How could Spring create your Order bean? What should it pass as argument to its constructor and why?

Comment: Thank You JB Nizet ! You showed me where a problem is.
I added this bean to Config class:

    @Bean
         public IOrder order (List<IBeer> beer) {
             return new Order(beer);
    }

and is OK.